# Remove ‘Customer payment page’ restrictions for admins in WooCommerce (pay_for_order capability?)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m interested in removing the restriction which prevents anyone other than the customer paying for their order, so that an admin can step in and do the payment on behalf of the customer for when customers have trouble making the payment themselves for any reason.

Currently if a customer makes an order and fails the payment, the link to ‘Customer payment page’ from the order edit screen takes you to a message that says:

> This order cannot be paid for. Please contact us if you need
>   assistance.

This is the restriction I’m trying to remove – I’ve narrowed it down to this code;

```
// Logged in customer trying to pay for someone else's order.
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'pay_for_order', $order_id ) ) {
                throw new Exception( __( 'This order cannot be paid 
for. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
```

Which is in file:

/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php

Which appears to reference a user capability.

What would be the best way of giving admins the capability to ‘pay_for_order’ for any order?

Many thanks for any help you can give

Comment: hey you can add the cabaility to the admin role see this post for an example https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74853/apply-custom-role-capabilities-to-administrator-without-plugin or it might just be easier to modify that code to allow admins meaning adding an or condition to that if statement. I would recommend the first as if you modify this file it will be updated in an update.

Answer (score 5):

This is a really rough example but it is what you are looking for. You can add this to your functions.php file. This will give the administrator role that capability.

```
function allow_admin_to_pay_for_order(){

     $administrator = get_role('administrator');
     $administrator->add_cap( 'pay_for_order' );
}

add_action('init', 'allow_admin_to_pay_for_order');
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will give this a try :)

Comment: Hello. What if I want guests to pay for the orders? (without having users to sign in)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "User Role Editor" Plugin, you can do it without code.
Just add the capability and make sure that the checkbox is activated for the desired role.
[image: Add capability screen]

[image: Checked capability]